# invoking function and command using awk

Tags: linux, bash, function, awk

Hi this script works fine, it calls the function when there a cronjob running under root

```
usage ()
{
# Print usage
       echo "usage function"
}
#

export -f usage
ps -ef | awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root") {system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage") }}'
```

However, in addition to calling the function I also like to print $2 or just call a second command. I cannot get the syntax  right.  Can someone help please. in short, how do you run multiple commands when the condition is met?  In the example above, in addition to running the usage() function I also like to run a second function and also print $2 ( which is the process ID ).  Thanking you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running multiple commands separated by semicolon

For example :

```
ps -ef | awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root") {system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage"); system("/usr/bin/env bash -c func2"); print $2 }}'
```

Answer (score 2):

For Bash, you can use `;` or `&&` to chain together commands.

`;` is used to separate commands, but does not check the error code of the previous command.  e.g. `dddate; echo 'hi'` will echo 'hi', even though "dddate" likely returns an error.

`&&` will only run the latter command if the previous command doesn't throw an error.  e.g. `dddate && echo 'hi'`will not run the `echo` command because `dddate` failed.

For your usage, you could make:

`system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage")` into `system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage); print $2"`.

```
root@debian:~# ps -ef | awk '{if ($0 ~ /crond/ && $1 == "root") {system("/usr/bin/env bash -c usage"); print "hi"}}'
usage function
hi
```

Comment: Thx. To be more specific, I want to use awk print in the example above. I tried ; and print $2 ) but it returns blank. Can u help?

Comment: `;` will combine your commands.  That's its purpose.  If you don't give a $2 argument, of course nothing will print for $2.  edited the answer with proof it works.